# Flip Output of SAT problem

Tags: np, satisfiability, co-np

Why cant I Just create a TM A that runs a NTM B with a formula to compute the SAT Problem and Just Flip its Output. So when the Input NTM B Returns true (formula is satisfyable) the TM A Return false.

Comment: does this answer your question
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21613/why-cant-we-flip-the-answer-of-a-ndtm-efficiently

Comment: @narekBojikian thank you! Thats what I was looking for